# Typed DefaultListModel to avoid casting

Tags: java, generics, list, model, casting

Is there a way in java to have a ListModel that only accepts a certain type?
What I'm looking for is something like `DefaultListModel<String>` or `TypedListModel<String>`, because the DefaultListModel only implements `addElement(Object obj)` and `get(int index)` which returns `Object` of course.

That way I always have to cast from `Object` to e.g. `String` and there is no guarantee that there are only strings in my model, even though I'd like to enforce that.

Is this a flaw or am I using list models the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class DefaultListModel does have this up the top in the source:

> This class loosely implements the `java.util.Vector`
>     API, in that it implements the 1.1.x version of
>     `java.util.Vector`, has no collection class support,
>     and notifies the `ListDataListener`s when changes occur. 
>     Presently it delegates to a `Vector`,
>     in a future release it will be a real Collection implementation.

Sounds like it's just an old class. I guess you could write your own version of it (implement the AbstractListModel interface) if you are desperate enough. If you are just annoyed about having to cast it to a String all the time surely the foreach syntax will do that for you?